# How to search the highest value with Java

Tags: java, arrays, search

I have writtin below code to search the highest value in 1 dimensional array. But it's not working due to some error. Below is the code:

```
   import java.io.*;

public class theHigest{
    int max = 0;
    int[] value = new int[5];
    BufferedReader objInput = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));

    public static void main(String[]args){
        theHigest obj6 = new theHigest();
        obj6.input();
        }

    void input(){
        try{
            for(int i=0;i<=4;i++){
                    System.out.println("===========================");
                    System.out.print("Value input-"+(i+1));
                    value[i]= Integer.parseInt(objInput.readLine());
                    System.out.println("===========================");
                }
            }
        catch(Exception e){
            System.out.println("Error "+ e);
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

You have not yet implemented any functionality for searching highest element in array. You can add little piece of code in your input function itself. There is no need for sorting. It'll cause you nlogn whereas you can do better than it just by simply traversing your array once. It will cost O(n).

```
void input(){
    try{
        for(int i=0;i<=4;i++){
                System.out.println("===========================");
                System.out.print("Value input-"+(i+1));
                value[i]= Integer.parseInt(objInput.readLine());
                System.out.println("===========================");
            }
     // searching for highest element in array
        int highest = value[0];
        for(int i=1;i<=4;i++){
               if(value[i]>highest){
                    highest = value[i];
                 }
            }
        System.out.println("The Highest is :: "+ highest);
        }
    catch(Exception e){
        System.out.println("Error "+ e);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a reference code to explain the concept. Kindly refer it & debug your code accordingly.

```
public class FindLargestSmallestNumber {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

            //array of 10 numbers
            int numbers[] = new int[]{32,43,53,54,32,65,63,98,43,23};

            //assign first element of an array to largest and smallest
            int smallest = numbers[0];
            int largest = numbers[0];

            for(int i=1; i< numbers.length; i++)
            {
                    if(numbers[i] > largest)
                            largest = numbers[i];
                    else if (numbers[i] < smallest)
                            smallest = numbers[i];

            }

            System.out.println("Largest Number is : " + largest);
            System.out.println("Smallest Number is : " + smallest);
    }
```

}

Output of this program would be

Largest Number is : 98

Smallest Number is : 23

Answer (score 0):

You can find max using below code:

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.util.Arrays;

public class TheMax {

    int max = 0;
    int[] values = new int[5];
    BufferedReader objInput = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
            System.in));

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        TheMax obj6 = new TheMax();
        obj6.input();
    }

    void input() {
        try {
            for (int i = 0; i <= 4; i++) {
                System.out.println("===========================");
                System.out.print("Value input [" + (i + 1) +"] :: ");
                values[i] = Integer.parseInt(objInput.readLine());
                System.out.println("===========================");
            }
            Arrays.sort(values);
            System.out.println("The Max is :: "+ values[values.length - 1]);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println("Error " + e);
        }
    }
}
```